# How to render mathml which retrieved by restful api with mathjax dynamically

Tags: vuejs2, mathjax

I have a vue project using mathjax to render partial html files which include some mathml inside. Those files are dynamically retrieved from remote server when customers search something and shown with vue v-html as raw html.

In details, all these occurs in the component 'Home', in the mounted function, I add mathjax related script as below:

```
const mathjaxScript = document.createElement('script');
mathjaxScript.setAttribute('id', 'MathJax-script');
mathjaxScript.setAttribute('async', 'async');
mathjaxScript.setAttribute('src', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js');
document.head.appendChild(mathjaxScript);
```

Then when customers search some keyword, corresponding partial html file will be retrieved and replace v-html tag, the math equation should be shown expectedly. However, those embeded mml:math tags weren't handled, they are just plain text, the math equation not handled correctly.

However, when I put one partial html in the vue template (not dynamically retrieve from remote server), the math equation rendered correctly. the mml:math tag will be replaced with mjx-container, etc.

So my question is: how to apply mathjax to those dynamically retrieved mathml? that is, rendering mathml on the fly with mathjax, Thanks.

Note: I use vuejs, mathjax 3 and typescript.

Comment: need to know about the same. as I need to render the MathML in vuejs but it is not happening as vuejs does not refresh the page

Comment: you need to use nextTick function